# How can I insert the value from an HTML input field into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, date

How can I insert the value from an  (in a form) into a MySQL date field. I'm trying this:

```
<form  action="enviar.php" autocomplete="off" method="post"> 
    <label for="nacimiento" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">
        Fecha de Nacimiento
    </label>
    <br>
    <input id="nacimiento" name="nacimiento"
           required type="datetime" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
</form>
```

enviar.php

```
$nacimiento= $_POST['nacimiento'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO voluntarios(nacimiento) VALUES ('$nacimiento')");`
```

This is working for all the other fields but not with the date field; it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Use parameterized SQL queries or you _Will_ get hacked. Your site is currently wide open to SQL injection. See http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: The mysql_ functions are deprecated (ie, they will be removed in the future).  Switch to mysqli_ or better still, to PDO.  Rearding your problem, are you sure your database will accept a date string formatted as dd/mm/yyyy ?  More than likely the correct format will have to be YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: As @Lusitanian stated, you should use parameterized queries (e.g. PDO) unless you have a very good reason not to. Otherwise, you can do like this: `$nacimiento = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nacimiento']);`

Comment: Can you please check the format of the string. Little know fact about datetime fields is that the browser transforms them before sending.

Comment: 1. You are not sanitizing your input. 2. You are using `mysql_` instead of `mysqli_`. Use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/en/manual/book.mysqli.php) and `mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO voluntarios(nacimiento) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($nacimiento) . "')");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [seem to have problems even getting the value from your `input` field to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621514/how-can-i-insert-the-value-from-an-html-input-field-into-mysql/11621598#comment15389864_11621582). This needs to get fixed first. [Debug](http://xdebug.org/) ([`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php)) your `$_POST` data and check what is going on. [Provide more code](http://jsfiddle.net/WzuzR/1/) if you need more help. From what you write, I don't see, why the value shouldn't get sent.

After you got your date string, [convert](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) the value to a string literal format [MySQL recognizes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
```

Then insert it using [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php):

```
mysqli_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO voluntarios(nacimiento) VALUES ('%s')"),
                      mysql_real_escape_string($mysqldate));
```

Using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) do this:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$q = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO voluntarios(nacimiento) VALUE (:nacimiento)");
$q->bindParam(':nacimiento', $mysqldate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$success = $q->execute();
```

Comment: @Wolfram please check the entire code of the form in JSFIDDLE. Thank you

Comment: Doing a var_dump I saw that I had an error in the variable, this was fixed. Now ´$nacimiento´ is taking the date and I can store it in  the database. At this time I am reading & learning about PDO to do secure codes.

Answer (score 2):

Try and echo `$_POST['nacimiento'];` and see if it does anything? It also seems that you're not posting your whole SQL query, maybe there is an error in the query?

Edit: You could also try and see what the error is using [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

---

The following code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
$nacimiento= $_POST['nacimiento'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO voluntarios(nacimiento) VALUES ('$nacimiento')");`
```

Stop using mysql_* functions as they're deprecated. Use [PHP database objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead because PDO allows parameter binding which protects you from sql injection.

You can read up on using PDO [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Comment: Or use mysqli, which is simpler than PDO. either way the raw mysql functions are deprecated.

Comment: doing echo $_POST['nacimiento']; the result is empty

Comment: @Aatch - _simpler_ is just a matter of opinion, but I think PDO is more widely adopted which is why I recommended it :)

Comment: the first part of the query is mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db ("DB");

Comment: Right okay, so you're connected to the database, if $_POST['nacimiento'] is coming up as empty then it most likely a problem with your form

Comment: @kush PDO stands for *PHP* Data Objects not protected database objects.

Comment: @ErickArias - What do you get with `var_dump($_POST['nacimiento']);`?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL expects date literals in YYYY-MM-DD format [as explained in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html).  Although it's pretty lenient in what it accept, the format you offer won't be acceptable.

You could get away with some string juggling probably, but do yourself a favor and *do it right* - that is, use [PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  Not only will you be able to easily defer date parsing & pre-checking to php, your code will be a lot safer and future proof.

The code will look like this, using elements from your example

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO voluntarios(nacimiento) VALUES (:nacimiento)");
$stmt->bindParam(':nacimiento', $nacimiento);
// WARNING - strtotime strtotime expects '-' separators if you feed it dd-mm-yyyy
// you should modify that in your form.
$nacimiento = strtotime($_POST['nacimiento']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely that the date needs to be formatted into the SQL standard (YYYY-MM-DD).

If you are fairly confident with what will be coming to you in the POST, then you can use this:

```
$formatted_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['nacimiento']));
```

If you want to ensure the format then you could use something like this:

```
preg_match('#^(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})$#', $_POST['nacimiento'], $matches);
if(count($matches))
{
    $formatted_date = $matches[3].'-'.str_pad($matches[1],2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT).'-'.str_pad($matches[2],2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    // Use formatted date in query
}
else // handle error
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the text into a valid date format:

```
STR_TO_DATE('12/15/2008', '%m/%d/%Y');
```